Disconnect and reconnect wifi in Android
I want disconnect and reconnect wifi in Android, but this disconnect and reconnect method was deprecated in the API at version 29:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />

Context context = requireContext();
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if (wifiManager != null && wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
        wifiManager.disconnect();
        wifiManager.reconnect();
        System.out.println(wifiManager.disconnect());
        System.out.println(wifiManager.reconnect());
    }

I found these notes in the Android Studio documentation:

This method was deprecated in API level 29.
a) See WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder#build() for new mechanism to trigger connection to a Wi-Fi network.
b) See addNetworkSuggestions(java.util.List), removeNetworkSuggestions(java.util.List) for new API to add Wi-Fi networks for consideration when auto-connecting to wifi. Compatibility Note: For applications targeting Build.VERSION_CODES.Q or above, this API will always fail and return false. Deprecation Exemptions:,

but I don't know how to solve this problem.
